# Counting poles that are shared between $f$ and $g$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Suppose I have a meromorphic function $f(z)$ with poles at $f_i$ and $\mathcal{Res}(f,f_i)=1$, and $g(z)$ with poles at $g_i$ and $\mathcal{Res}(g,g_i)=1$.

I would like to construct a function $P(z)$:
$$C_{f,g}(\gamma)=\oint_\gamma P(z)\,dz=\sum_{f_i=g_i\in D}1$$
where $D$ is the region bounded by $\gamma$. $P$ has only poles where both $g$ and $f$ has with residue $1$, so $C$ counts the shared poles. I have no idea how to do this, or if it is possible in general. Is there any way to construct such a $P$?

**Edit:**

Since $f$ and $g$ can be quite complex, I don't know a formula for the poles. I am looking forward to construct $P$ only using the definition of $f$ and $g$.

**Example:**

$$f(z)={1\over z-i}+{1\over z+1}+{1\over z}$$
$$g(z)={1\over z-i}+{1\over z+2}+{1\over z}$$
$$P(z)={1\over2\pi i}\left({1\over z-i}+{1\over z}\right)$$

Comment: $x$ is not used and the denominator is always zero. Are you sure?

Comment: f and g can be quite complex, so maybe I do not have a formula for the poles, thus cannot determine the sum.

Comment: @Adayah : I didn't notice the denominator was $0$. But yes, making a constant function was intended. Fixed trivial example : $$P(z)=\frac{\sum_{f_i=g_i\in D}1}{2\pi i}\frac{1}{z}$$

Comment: @xavierm02: But what's $D$?

Comment: @xavierm02 this should work, but the problem is with the sum. I want to determine that with $P$, not the other way around.

Comment: @Adayah : Whatever the OP meant by $D$. The interior of $\gamma$ I guess.

Comment: @ Adayah $D$ is the region bounded by $\gamma$

Comment: Wait, are $D$ and $\gamma$ fixed? I thought they were supposed to be arbitrary.

Comment: they are arbitary, the purpose of the whole thing is to create a $P$ that has only poles where both $f$ and $g$ has.

Comment: So they aren't given at the beginning and you can't define $P$ like above.

Comment: I add an example to clarify things.

Comment: How about something like $$z\mapsto\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{h(f(z))}+\cfrac{1}{h(g(z))}}$$ assuming you can find $h$ so that $|z|\to \infty \iff h(z) \to \infty$

Comment: @pndev : There's still the problem of finding a "nice" $h$ so that your contour integral is actually defined. And then there's the fact that the bottom sum can be $0$ when the second summand is the opposite of the first, even if they are both not $0$.

Comment: I see. It gave me a starting point, so next problem is to find a $h$. $f$ and $g$ I work with are mainly simple functions, so it is maybe easier.